# Upgrade to 1.9.2.2 - Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mage_permission_variable' already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, table, ce-1.9.2.2

I am trying to upgrade to 1.9.2.2 from 1.9.2.1 through Magento Downloader.  On the screen at the bottom, I am getting the error message below:

> Exception during cache and session cleaning: Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mage_permission_variable' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `mage_permission_variable` ( `variable_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Variable ID' , `variable_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'Config Path' , `is_allowed` bool NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Mark that config can be processed by filters' , PRIMARY KEY (`variable_id`, `variable_name`), UNIQUE `UNQ_MAGE_PERMISSION_VARIABLE_VARIABLE_NAME` (`variable_name`) ) COMMENT='System variables that can be processed via content filter' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci.........................

It repeats this quite a few times and then just stays there and the website is broken.

I'm not at all technical with Magento - could someone help me diagnose what's wrong and how I fix it (in as simple steps as possible!)?

Comment: I saw another post and if I delete 'upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php' then everything appears to work.  Is it OK to just delete this file or will it cause me problems in the future?

Comment: i think you already had applied patch-6788 that creates variable and permissions block. So do not delete the file just comment out that sql code and run setup. After successful run uncomment code.

Answer (score 0):

That means you already have the `mage_permission_variable` table in your database.
Don't delete the file instead of you can drop `mage_permission_variable` and `mage_permission_block` table then continue you upgrading process

it will do the trick....

Don't forget to backup the database before dropping those tables

Hope it helps

Comment: These tables are from a previous patch the OP has maybe installed. The tables might have some custom values - I mean, at least the  `mage_permission_block` table will have entries. He should not simply drop them, because blocks that are not in the default configuration will miss from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment the code which create the db table **mage_permission_variable** in file **upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php**